# Can you please identify this houseplant that has long floppy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

[image: House plant identification]

Long green, floppy leaves with spotty undersides.

Comment: Have you ever seen a flower on this plant? How long have you had it and has it always had these floppy leaves, or does it disappear completely at times?

Comment: Is it in a bark medium? Looks kinda like an orchid.

Comment: @J.Musser looks like hydro grains.

Comment: What kind of soil is it in?

Comment: It could be an orchid. Those do look like hydroton or something similar. I've got a few in semi-hydro. I'm not sure if that's the setup here or not. I couldn't tell you for sure it's an orchid, though. We could use some more pics.

Comment: Do you recall any flowers ever? What about Eucomis bicolor? See https://goo.gl/ZNZ38Q

Answer (score 1):

This is a corn plant..solid leaf
D. fragrans
The original, with solid green leaves. The original is the least common and of course it will have its fans but the variegated versions outsell this one massively.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a corn plant as it does not have a woody stem that the leaves are attached to.

Comment: Seems odd, but when they're smaller or grown from kernels that you'd find in bird food - this is what a corn plant looks like.  If unhealthy, the leaves will peel back from the center like this one's has.  Not saying 100%, but I get tons of these every year on my tree line from the corn feed I toss out.

Comment: If using latin names remember to include the genus, species by itself is not that helpful - there are quite a few *D. fragrans* out there of which *Dracaena fragrans* is only one; even it seems obvious to you which one it is (to many it won't be). I'm also not convinced by your ident.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an orchid to me as well. not a very healthy one. The leaves should be firm and stand up. Google care of orchids. I  believe by the looks of it that its not too far gone that it can't recover.